# insert json_encode values into mysql table

Tags: php, json

I am working in PHP.I have the following values which is done the json_encode function.When i print the variable $vmndetails i got the below details.

```
[{
   "id":"1",
   "smsid":"4781366",
   "senderid":"289613638",
   "textcontent":"Good day reply",
   "msgdate":"2014-12-17 13:04:20",
   "charsetval":"UTF-8",
   "userid":"",
   "reprtdate":"2014-12-17 11:04:21"
},   
{
   "id":"7",
   "smsid":"4781467",
   "senderid":"289761363",
   "textcontent":"Good",
   "msgdate":"2014-12-17 13:21:18",
   "charsetval":"UTF-8",
   "userid":"",
   "reprtdate":"2014-12-17 11:21:21"
}]
```

I have to insert these values into my mysql table.

So i wrote the below function.

```
mysql->query( "INSERT INTO twowaysms(id,smsid,senderid,textcontent,msgdate,charsetval,userid,reprtdate) VALUES "."(" . implode(",",$vmndetails) . ")");
```

But i am getting an error that 'Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'.I have seen the same question a lot here but i cannot find a solution.How to solve the issue?Please anyone help me..

Comment: make sure your `$vmndetails` variable holds the values that matchs with the total numbers of columns

Comment: **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** join array elements not array of object elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have mulit-dimensional array data, so try like this -

```
// http://ideone.com/xX2HNU
$vmndetails = '[{"id":"1","smsid":"4781366","senderid":"289613638","textcontent":"Good day reply","msgdate":"2014-12-17 13:04:20","charsetval":"UTF-8","userid":"","reprtdate":"2014-12-17 11:04:21"},{"id":"7","smsid":"4781467","senderid":"289761363","textcontent":"Good","msgdate":"2014-12-17 13:21:18","charsetval":"UTF-8","userid":"","reprtdate":"2014-12-17 11:21:21"}]';

$vmndetails = json_decode($vmndetails, true);
$values = "";
foreach($vmndetails as $v) {
    $values .= "(".implode(", ", $v)."), "
}
$values = rtrim($values, ", ");

mysql->query( "INSERT INTO 
    wowaysms(id,smsid,senderid,textcontent,msgdate,charsetval,userid,reprtdate) 
    VALUES {$values} ");
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the reply.Its working.There is a small issue,i have given datatype of some details as varchar in table,so single quotes should be there for insertion of values.When i am echoing the insert query values are not having single quotes.What can we do for that?

Comment: Yes.I got it correctly.I have edited your code like:                                                                   $values .= "('".implode("','", $v)."'), ";                                                                   It works fine.Thank you so much.

Comment: @ElizabethJoshy you have to accept this answer if it helps you.

Comment: @jogesh_pi I gave you my +1, Mrs Elizabeth has been pretty unkind. 
Let's suppose we have an html form with sooo maaany inputs fields. We collect them as object input1-valueinput1 up to input30-valueinput30
Then we use javascript JSON.stringify to create a json array-string and we POST it to our php process
On the php side we income the POST and we can e.g. json&#95;decode the string to a php array. Naming properly both input (html side) and db fields, do you think is possible to make the insert even more automatic?

Comment: @jogesh_pi formerly avoid setting the 30 fields names in the query.